# Confusion between local variables, instance variables, and symbols

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

```
class​ BookInStock
  attr_reader :isbn, :price
  ​def​ initialize(isbn, price) 
    @isbn  = isbn
    @price = Float(price)
  ​end​
```

“This is the first time we’ve used ​ symbols​ in this chapter. As we discussed, symbols are just a convenient way of referencing a name. In this code, you can think of ​:isbn​ as meaning the ​name ​ ​isbn​ and think of plain ​isbn​ as meaning the ​value​ of the variable. In this example, we named the accessor methods ​isbn​ and ​price​. The corresponding instance variables are ​@isbn​ and ​@price​. ”

**Question:** I understand that the local variables are assigned instance variables, so that they don't disappear when the the initialize method returns. But why do I have to use symbols with attr_accessor? What if I just want normal variables instead? I noticed that removing the colons for :isbn and :price in attr_accessor causes it to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Symbols aren't really variables; they are more like special strings. For instance, your code would work just fine if you used strings instead:

```
class​ BookInStock
  attr_reader 'isbn', 'price'

  ​def​ initialize(isbn, price) 
    @isbn  = isbn
    @price = Float(price)
  ​end
end
```

It's more a matter of convention than of functionality really. On idiomatic Ruby symbols are commonly used to name options, for example.

To get an extensive explanation on the differences between symbols and strings, check out this blog post: [The Difference Between Ruby Symbols and Strings](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/).

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your code as follows:

```
class BookInStock
  attr_name1 = "isbn"
  attr_name2 = :price
  attr_reader attr_name1, attr_name2
  def initialize(isbn, price) 
    @isbn  = isbn
    @price = Float(price)
  end
end

b = BookInStock.new("23456", 30.3)
puts b.isbn
puts b.price
```

Statament in class definiton body is executed the same way as statement out of class definition body. "attr_reader attr_name1, attr_name2" is not a delaration, it's just a normal statement which calls method attr_reader with two arguments, attr_name1 and attr_name. attr_reader is a method defined in Module.